# Entity Framework Complex query with inner joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to execute a complex query using Entity Framework (Code First).

I know it can be done by LINQ, but what is the best way to write LINQ query for complex data and inner joining?

I want to execute the following query:

```
var v = from m in WebAppDbContext.UserSessionTokens
                from c in WebAppDbContext.Companies.Include(a => a.SecurityGroups)
                from n in WebAppDbContext.SecurityGroups.Include(x => x.Members)
                where m.TokenString == userTokenString &&
                n.Members.Contains(m.User) &&
                c.SecurityGroups.Contains(n)
                select c;
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Does this query get any entire list of records from the db and then executes the filtration on this list? (might be huge list)

And most important: Does it query the database several times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL:DR; don't micromanage the robots. Let them do their thing and 99% of the time you'll be fine. Linq doesn't really expose methods to micromanage the underlying data query, anyway, its whole purpose is to be an abstraction layer.

In my experience, the Linq provider is pretty smart about converting valid Linq syntax into "pretty good" SQL. Your looks like your query is all inner joins, and those should all be on the primary indexes/foreign keys of each table, so it's going to come up with something pretty good.

If that's not enough to soothe your worries, I'd suggest:

1. put on a SQL Trace to see the actual query that's being presented to the Database. I bet it's not as simple as Companies join SecurityGroups join Members join UserTokens, but it's probably equivalent to it.
2. Only worry about optimizing if this becomes an actual performance problem.
3. If it does become a performance problem, consider refactoring your problem space. It looks like you're trying to get a Company record from a UserToken, by going through three other tables. Is it possible to just relate Users and Companies directly, rather than through the security model? (please excuse my total ignorance of your problem space, I'm just saying "maybe look at the problem from another angle?")

In short, it sounds like you're burning brain cycles attempting to optimize something prematurely. Now, it's reasonable to think if there *is* a performance problem, this section of the code could be responsible, but that would only be noticeable if you're doing this query *a lot*. Based on coming from a security token, I'd guess you're doing this once per session to get the current user's contextual information. In that case, the problem isn't usually with Linq, but with your approach to solving the problem for finding Company information. Can you cache the result?

Comment: Sorry this is more of a "Programmers" answer than a "Stack Overflow" answer. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion and based on my own experiences, talking about performance, especially joining data sets, it's faster when you write it in SQL. But since you used code first approach then it's not an option. To answer your questions, your query will not query DB several times (you can try debugging and see Events log in VS). EF will transform your query into SQL statement and execute it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to know how can I run such a query in correct manner and what is the best way to do so.

Comment: Jacob, for the most part, if it compiles in C#, the Linq provider will transform it into pretty-close-to-correct SQL, even in your gnarly example. I'd suggest putting on the SQL Trace so you can see the query for yourself, if you're concerned.